# Error after applying metadata (with category) on page

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, java

I have created a metadata schema which has a dropdown field referring to a particular catrgory. 
When I apply the metadata on page and publish the page, I get internal server error.

Error message:

> 2015-09-05 04:00:44,039 ERROR JSONSerializer - Error deserializing.
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of org.dd4t.contentmodel.Category, problem: abstract types
>   either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer,
>   or be instantiated with additional type information  at [Source:
>   {"RevisionDate":"2015-09-05T13:00:27.693","Filename........
>   .....................................................................
>   .......................................................................... ;
>   line: 1, column: 17721] (through reference chain:
>   org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.PageImpl["Categories"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

When I apply similar metadata on Structure Group, the pages work fine.

I am passing the values of these metadata schemas to GenerateSitemap TBB. Do I need to use any special data-type for category and keywords? Currently I am using string and navigation.json is formed correctly.

We are using java DXA.

**Update:**

This issue also occurs on pages which do not have navigation. So I suspect its not related to sitempap TBB or navigation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug in the dd4t-2 beta stack. Since you are using (probably?) a mixed set of DXA-Java and a dd4t-2 stack, I'm not sure where it should be fixed.

In any case, the actual fix is in `org.dd4t.contentmodel.PageImpl`:

```
// change this line:

@JsonProperty("Categories")
private List categories;

// Into this line:

@JsonProperty("Categories") @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = CategoryImpl.class)
private List categories;
```

Comment: This is fixed in the SDL DXA 1.2 (Java) release https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/1